# Reuse objects among subsequent requests to dynamic Google App Engine backend

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

on my GAE app, I have a servlet that performs an XSLT transformation. I used to run it as frontent, but sometimes it took too much time to finish. So I'm now running this on the backend.

This is what I did:
1/ create a file 'backends.xml' defining a dynamic public backend named 'xslt'
2/ prepend 'xslt' to the domain when calling the servlet:

```
http://xslt.[appname].appspot.com/getCoordinates?[params]
```

This works!

The typical behaviour of the app is that a series of calls to this 'getCoordinates' servlet will be made. Each request will trigger the 'doGet' method of this 'getCoordinates' servlet, which does the initialization of the Saxon processor, xsltCompiler, xsltExecutable and xsltTransformer, but all of these objects could be reused across subsequent requests!

*My question:* **how should I program to separate this initialization code into a handler for the backend initialization request to '_ah/start'?**

If I just create another servlet 'startXslt' that answers the request to '_ah/start' and initialize all the generic objects within this servlet's 'doGet' method, how will I be able to use the objects from within the 'getCoordinates' servlet's 'doGet' method?

(I'm not very experienced with java servlet programming, so I reckon this may be more like a general question on java servlet programming, and not GAE-specific, or is it?)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's general questions, and there is really a hundreds of ways of doing that. Btw, most projects are based on some framework, and it depends on it. If you're startd with plain raw servlets - i strongly recommend you to take a look at other options. For GAE there is [Gaelyk](http://gaelyk.appspot.com/). Or [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) MVC as most populart (is it?) general usage framework.

Btw, if you need an solution right now, I can recommend one of the following:

- init in [init()](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Servlets6.html) method (it will be called on app startup)
- store it at [class static field](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=249930), and init in `static {}` block (called at class initialization, shared between instances)
- make an [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for this transformers (you can init it once, at first call)

Answer (score 0):

Using a backend is a good idea, since you could control that only a single instance would be used and re-used when addressing the backend.

In this way, all servlets would be executed within the same JVM instance, and you could therefore have a shared object by using a Singleton pattern as suggested by splix on the other answer.

As I understand it, your question pertains on how you could hook on the backend initialization to initialize your own objects. If that is the case, you could implement a [ServletContextListener](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Using_a_ServletContextListener) and put your code on the `contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent)` method.

This method would be invoked once every time a new instance is created, be it at the front end or at the back end.